# AngularJs failed to read pre defined input value

Tags: angularjs

My code like

```
 <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
 <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here" value="something" ></p>
 <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
```

I want to display output like

```
Input something in the input box:
**Hello something** (by default)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-init` in your case like  `ng-init="name='somthing'"`

**Markup**

```
<p ng-init="name='somthing'">Input something in the input box:</p>
 <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here" /></p>
 <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
```